# issue with glDebugMessageCallback on Windows 10 using freeglut

Tags: c++, windows, opengl

I would like to use `glDebugMessageCallback' function as an aid to debug my openGL
program.  I've implemented my debug callback as:

```
void MyDbgCallback(GLenum source, GLenum type, GLenum id, GLenum severity, GLsizei length, const GLchar* msg, GLvoid* user)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "GL CALLBACK: %s type = 0x%x, severity = 0x%x, message = %s\n", (type == GL_DEBUG_TYPE_ERROR ? "** GL ERROR **" : ""), type, severity, msg);
}
```

as shown in the example located here: https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Debug_Output
Additionall, I have include the following two lines during initialization:

```
// Enable debugging output
glEnable(GL_DEBUG_OUTPUT);
glDebugMessageCallback(MyDbgCallback, 0);
```

Now on compilation (VS2015), I get the following error message:

```
1>error C2664: 'void (GLDEBUGPROC,const void *)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'overloaded-function' to 'GLDEBUGPROC'
1> note: None of the functions with this name in scope match the target type
```

From searching the web (including this site), I've seen multiple post that the last argument in the callback function should be `const GLvoid* user`, and I've tried it both ways with the same error.

Mousing over the red-squiggly lines in the IDE I get the following message: "argument of type void(*)(GLenum souce, GLenum type, GLenum id, GLenum severity, GLsizei length, const GLchar* msg, GLvoid* user) is incompatible with a parameter of type GLDEBUGPROC".  Now searching though header files, I find `GLDEBUGPROC` declared on line 2709 of `glcorearb.h`, and it is declared as:

```
typedef void (APIENTRY *GLDEBUGPROC)(GLenum source,GLenum type,GLuint id,GLenum severity,GLsizei length,const GLchar *message,GLvoid *userParam);
```

Which looks identical to the DbgCallback function that I am using.  What am I missing?  What do I need to do to get this to work on Windos 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `APIENTRY` part of the function declaration is not optional. Your function doesn't provide this specifier, which likely forces the compiler to use C-style calling conventions for the function, which the caller of that callback would be expecting. The compiler is trying to save you from harder-to-debug errors later on.

Also, you shouldn't overload callbacks like this. One definition is enough.

Comment: The APIENTRY got by the compilation error, sadly a linking error "LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _gl3wDebugMessageCallback" resulted...guess it's time to look at what version of `gl3w` i have and if that needs to be updated.  Also, I only have one definition of the callback, I was curious about the 'overload-function' part of the error message...didn't make sense because I didn't overload anything.